# Can a moderator just decide to transfer the ownership of my question to the community?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki

Okay an hour my question: [Do mathematicians, in the end, always agree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962449/do-mathematicians-in-the-end-always-agree) was made community wiki. I didn't know what community wiki meant, and why my post should have made community wiki, so I googled it, and I read that:

> Community wiki posts work by transferring ownership of the post from the original author to the community.

So, at first sight, I was a little bit like, can somebody else just decide that I'm not the owner of my own question anymore? And why this does this moderator think that I don't deserve to have the ownership of my own question ? I'm the only one that has edited this question ...

Reading a little bit more, I understand now that my question is probably made community wiki so that I don't gain reputation from it. This I do understand, I also noticed that the highest upvoted question I've asked, where soft-question and the reputation I get from these soft-question doesn't really reflect my knowledge about mathematics.

I don't care so much about reputation, I'm fine with that aspect, but I do feel this is a little bit the wrong way to solve this. Why not just make sure that questions tagged 'big-list' or 'soft-question' don't gain user reputation ?

Comment: The short answer to the question in the title: Yes, yes they can. (The slightly less shorter is that CW doesn't quite mean you're not the owner of the post anymore.)

Comment: The practice on this site is much more in favor of "ownership" (whatever that means) than other Stackexchange sites. Even when I mark things as community wiki, they are unlikely to be edited by others. But the software is the same as other sites, and that's something we can't avoid.

Answer (score 6):

> And why this does this moderator think

More often than not, moderators act in response to flags. It's likely that someone raised a mod attention flag, arguing that the question should be Community Wiki, and the moderator agreed after reviewing the case.

It's a software restriction that only moderators can make a question community wiki, unlike answers. This is why, no matter who actually wants the question CWed (often it's the author of the question), you will see a moderator doing it.

> Why not just make sure that questions tagged 'big-list' or 'soft-question' don't gain user reputation

All 130 Stack Exchange sites run on the same Q&A engine. The developers could theoretically code in the exception: on Mathematics site, questions with this or that tag should not accrue reputation. But it's not something they would do; they have better uses for their time. Besides, a policy like that would have to be documented, and then explained to every user who did not read the documentation. And the last point... what problem are we solving here?

Comment: Not to mention the nightmare that would ensue if the question were migrated to another site where these tags do give reputation.

Comment: @robjohn: Or the nightmare where you're falling into a bottomless chasm, chased by hypergravity-powered monsters, while sitting in your classroom when a pop quiz on a subject you cannot recall anything about is announced, and you suddenly realize that you're completely naked, with the exception of a headband which says "DOOMED".